# How to assert the text inside toast error message in selenium c#

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing, testing, xpath

In my application, a toast message(pop up) appears when i try to enter invalid cell phone number and i want to assert the text of that toast message.

Below is the image of my HTML.I am unable to copy paste here.

[image]

Below is the code tried but no such element error occurs.

```
String actual_error = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='toast-message']")).Text;
        String expected_error = "CellphoneNumber:Please enter a valid cellphone number. :";
        Assert.AreEqual(actual_error, expected_error);
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number error message validated successfully");
```

Kindly suggest the right way to assert the toast message.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;

namespace StackOverFlow.Answer.Selenium.AssertMessageText
{
    class AssertMessagePhone
    {
        public static IWebDriver driver;
        public static WebDriverWait wait;
        public static int timeOut = 30;

        [Test]
        [Category("ClickPartilLink")]
        public void AssertMessagePhoneTest()
        {
            string messageError = "CellphoneNumber:Please enter a valid cellphone number. :";

            Log.Information("Get instance Chrome Browser");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), OptionsChrome());

            Console.WriteLine("Acess your url site");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://YourUrlSite/index.aspx");

            // Steps until to fill and submit phone

            Log.Information("Wait notificantion message error");
            WaiElement(By.CssSelector(".toast-message"));

            Log.Information("Check message");
            Assert.True(GetText(By.CssSelector(".toast-message")).ToUpper().Contains(messageError.ToUpper()));

            Log.Information("Click on message to disaper");
            Click(By.CssSelector("div[class='noty_bar noty_type_success'] > div > span"));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wait elements
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="locator"></param>
        private void WaiElement(By locator)
        {
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeOut));
            wait.Until(condition: ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(locator));
        }      

        /// <summary>
        /// click on elements 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="locator"></param>
        private void Click(By locator)
        {
            WaiElement(locator);
            driver.FindElement(locator).Click();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// return text from element
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="locator"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private string GetText(By locator)
        {
            WaiElement(locator);
            return driver.FindElement(locator).Text;
        }        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your verification seems fine. You need to make sure that:
- your tests are in proper order if page is opened in another one
- make sure you wait for all elements, i.e use method:

```
ExpectedConditions.PresenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(/*element to test*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with lukbl that I would create a bool to verify the element it present but I believe the issue is that your text is in a div tag and not in a span.

Try this:

```
String expected_error = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='toast-message']/text()[1]")).Text;
```